# sha-256 mismatch between GooglePlay Console & built APK

Tags: android, deep-linking

AppLinks are not working in my project and this is the repport when doing an  `adb shell pm get-app-links myAppName.android`

```
myAppName.android:
    ID: ...
    Signatures: [96.86...]
    Domain verification state:
      myDomain.com: 1024
      staging.myDomain.com: 1024
      staging.mySubDomain.myDomain.com: 1024
      mySubDomain.myDomain.com: 1024
```

Nevertheless when I check the domain in Google Play Console, it is shown as working correctly (my assetlinks.json is downloable from myDomain/.well-known/assetlinks).

```
[
  {
    "relation": ["delegate_permission/common.handle_all_urls"],
    "target": {
      "namespace": "android_app",
      "package_name": "...",
      "sha256_cert_fingerprints":
        ["95.76..."]
    }
  }
]
```

With closer inspection I realized that the `sha256_cert_fingerprints` published and validated by Google Play Console doesn't match the one provided by my build using `adb shell pm get-app-links myAppName.android`

```
// Google Play Console -> ["95.76..."]
// adb shell pm get-app-links myAppName.android -> ["96.86..."]
```

How is that even possible and how do I correct this behavior and mismatch? Thanks in advance!

Comment: Do you use Google signing (where Google is signing the APK files users download) or do you have an old app where you upload a signed APK to Play Store?